# Storing a CLOB data from a table in a variable in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, clob

Let's say I have a column named "changedetail" with datatype "CLOB" in a table called "changelog".
Now, I want to store the value of "changedetail" in a new variable say "loginfo" when a column named "changeuid" is say "ABC1234" .
Please can someone help me in getting the sql query for this.

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide your code and show what did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying the following?

```
DECLARE
id_1 varchar2(32767); 
id_1 := 'Your sql';

INSERT INTO YOUR_TABLE (col1) 
VALUES (id_1);
END;
```